# What is the status of the Gennes - Alexander theory of Superconducting Micronetworks?

Tags: experimental-physics, superconductivity

I have started reading the book Connectivity and Superconductivity which gives an introduction to the ideas of de Gennes-Alexander theory. My question is: how is this theory regarded experimentally? Besides the sophisticated math approach,does it give good experimental results?